# Pandas aggregate groupby for specific values

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the below table,

```
ID#    dispute_amt   year   month
1234   12.50         2019   3
1234   4.00          2019   3
5678   100           2020   5
```

I want the desired table to be the following

```
ID#    dispute_count dispute_amt   year   month
1234   2             16            2019   3
5678   1             100           2020   5
```

The current table at the top has duplicated ID# with multiple disputes per month/year. I want to aggregate that at a unique ID# and then be able to count all of the disputes per ID# per month/year. I think i need to use some sort of groupby operator here but I have no idea how to actually do this using python/pandas.

Any help here would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby().agg()`

```
 df.groupby(['ID#', 'year', 'month']).agg(dispute_count =('dispute_amt','count')\
,dispute_amt=('dispute_amt','sum')).reset_index()

    ID#  year  month  dispute_count  dispute_amt
0  1234  2019      3              2         16.5
1  5678  2020      5              1        100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote that you want to aggregate for ID per year per month, You can yse groupby ID and reset index

```
 df
 .groupby(['ID#','year','month')['dispute_amt']
 .count().reset_index(name='dispute_count')
```